# OSX Python MPI accessing multiple MacBook Pro cores

Tags: python, macos, mpi

I'm having trouble accessing both cores on my early-2008 MacBook Pro (soon to be retired). I want some tasks (such as user input) to be carried out only once. It's possible both cores ARE being used, since there appears to be some speed-up with -np 2, but perhaps that's just because one of the cores is carrying two processes.

My Hello World is:

```
#!/bin/env python

"""
from www.siafoo.net/snippet/64
mpirun -np N_PROCS ./mpiHelloWorld.py
"""

from mpi4py import MPI
import sys

hwmess = "Hello, World!! I am process %d of %d on %s.\n"
myrank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank()
nprocs = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_size()
procnm = MPI.Get_processor_name()
sys.stdout.write(hwmess % (myrank, nprocs, procnm))
```

giving

$ mpirun -np 2 python mpiHelloWorld.py

Hello, World!! I am process 0 of 1 on localhost.

Hello, World!! I am process 0 of 1 on localhost.

nprocs is 1 when I think it should be 2. Other details:

$ which python
/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python
$ python
Enthought Python Distribution -- www.enthought.com
Version: 7.2-2 (64-bit)

Python 2.7.2 |EPD 7.2-2 (64-bit)| (default, Sep  7 2011, 16:31:15) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "packages", "demo" or "enthought" for more information.

mpirun --version gives:

$ mpirun --version
HYDRA build details:
    Version:                                 3.0.4
    Release Date:                            Wed Apr 24 10:08:10 CDT 2013
    CC:                              /usr/bin/gcc-4.2  -pipe -arch x86_64 -L/opt/local/lib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -arch x86_64 
    CXX:                             /usr/bin/g++-4.2  -pipe -arch x86_64 -L/opt/local/lib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -arch x86_64 
    F77:                             /opt/local/bin/gfortran-mp-4.8 -pipe -m64 -L/opt/local/lib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -arch x86_64 
    F90:                             /opt/local/bin/gfortran-mp-4.8 -pipe -m64 -L/opt/local/lib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -arch x86_64 
    Configure options:                       '--disable-option-checking' '--prefix=/opt/local' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--enable-f77' '--enable-fc' '--disable-silent-rules' '--enable-base-cache' '--enable-cache' '--enable-cxx' '--enable-fast=Os' '--enable-shared' '--enable-smpcoll' '--with-device=ch3:nemesis' '--with-pm=hydra' '--with-thread-package=posix' '--enable-versioning' 'F90FLAGS=' 'F90=' '--enable-timer-type=mach_absolute_time' 'CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2' 'CFLAGS=-pipe -arch x86_64 -Os' 'LDFLAGS=-L/opt/local/lib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -arch x86_64 ' 'CXX=/usr/bin/g++-4.2' 'CXXFLAGS=-pipe -arch x86_64 -Os' 'F77=/opt/local/bin/gfortran-mp-4.8' 'FFLAGS=-pipe -m64 -Os' 'FC=/opt/local/bin/gfortran-mp-4.8' 'FCFLAGS=-pipe -m64 -Os' '--cache-file=/dev/null' '--srcdir=.' 'LIBS=-lpthread ' 'CPPFLAGS= -I/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_science_mpich/mpich/work/mpich-3.0.4/src/mpl/include -I/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_science_mpich/mpich/work/mpich-3.0.4/src/mpl/include -I/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_science_mpich/mpich/work/mpich-3.0.4/src/openpa/src -I/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_science_mpich/mpich/work/mpich-3.0.4/src/openpa/src -I/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_science_mpich/mpich/work/mpich-3.0.4/src/mpi/romio/include'
    Process Manager:                         pmi
    Launchers available:                     ssh rsh fork slurm ll lsf sge manual persist
    Topology libraries available:            hwloc
    Resource management kernels available:   user slurm ll lsf sge pbs cobalt
    Checkpointing libraries available:
    Demux engines available:                 poll select

mpirun --nooversubscribe gives:

$ mpirun --nooversubscribe
[mpiexec@localhost] match_arg (./utils/args/args.c:160): unrecognized argument nooversubscribe
[mpiexec@localhost] HYDU_parse_array (./utils/args/args.c:175): argument matching returned error
[mpiexec@localhost] parse_args (./ui/mpich/utils.c:1609): error parsing input array
[mpiexec@localhost] HYD_uii_mpx_get_parameters (./ui/mpich/utils.c:1660): unable to parse user arguments
[mpiexec@localhost] main (./ui/mpich/mpiexec.c:153): error parsing parameters

The OS is Snow Leopard 10.6.8 and the chip is an Intel Core 2 Duo.

What else?

How can I access both cores?

Thanks!

Comment: Your mpi4py installation should contain a file called mpi.cfg. You should double check the contents of it match the location of your mpich installation.

Comment: Make sure that `mpi4py` module is compiled and linked against the same MPI library that provides the `mpirun` command. You can use `otool -L` on the compiled Python module to check that.

Comment: Fixed! I recompiled mpi4py - I think the damage was done by a later installation of mpicc.